# Fill combobox with SQL Server column values

Tags: c#, sql-server

Could you please assist me, I am trying to fill a combobox with values from a column in a SQL Server table. I have tried various methods, but none of them returned the desired result.

The error is:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillCombo();
    }

    void fillCombo()
    {
        string con = "Data Source = xxxxx; Initial Catalog = xxxxx; Integrated Security = False; User Id = xxxxx; Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        string Query = "select * from LEAVE ;";

        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        SqlDataReader dr;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string lveName = dr.GetString("lve_name");
                lveType.Items.Add(lveName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `dr.GetString` requires an `int` to be passed as an argument, you are passing a `string`.

Comment: Documentation is what you need. [SqlDataReader.GetString Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this instead:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lveNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    string lveName = dr["lve_name"].ToString();
    int lveId = int.Parse(dr["lve_id"].ToString());
    lveNames.Add(lveId, lveName);
}

lveType.DataSource = new BindingSource(lveNames, null);
lveType.DisplayMember = "lveName";
lveType.ValueMember = "lveId";
```

- Assuming that you have id `lve_id`.
- `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are used to bind the label and id to the combo box.

Comment: Hi Rafael Kho, thank you for your suggestion. May I ask why you would rather do it this way?

Comment: Why use a `BindingSource` at all instead of a simple custom class?

Answer (score 1):

Always look at the signatures of the methods you are trying to use:

```
dr.GetString(int)
```

You are trying to call

```
dr.GetString(string)
```

but there's not overloaded method that accepts a string. See [the documentation of GetString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Instead, `GetString` requires you to pass the zero based ordinal of the column you are trying to get the string from. Let's say `lve_name` is the second column in your query (a bit hard to tell, since you are using `SELECT * FROM`, but that's another topic), you have to use it like this:

```
string lveName = dr.GetString(1);
```

Also, check what the documentation has to say:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.

This means, if your query returns anything other than a string, the method will most likely throw an `InvalidCastException`. To prevent that from happening, you have to edit your query, like for example

```
SELECT lve_id, CAST(lve_name as varchar) FROM LEAVE
```

Another possible solution would be to access the column like this:

```
string lveName = dr["lve_name"].ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks waka, yes it is the 2nd column however when I try your string "string lveName = dr.GetString(1);" I get the following message "Unable to cast object of type 'SystemInt16' to Type System String"

Comment: However the second suggestion worked thank you! Was just curious about the first suggestion not working

Comment: @GerhardSteyn: This is because the query returns the data as `smallint`, it seems, `GetString` doesn't do any conversion. I have updated my answer accordingly.